# How can i prevent token abuse in Laravel Api using Password Grant flow

Tags: laravel, api, oauth

I'm using Password Grant flow in my Laravel api but i find that the tokens generated to the user may be abused.

I have the api running in a domain and a web app in another domain consuming it. I want to make sure that even if someone copy the token from the Localstorage inside my app, it will be useless outside of my consuming domain.

The only solution i find to this problem is by checking the domain with a middleware or inside the Api methods. Is there any secure way to do this? Should i use middlewares as i just mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I don't think there is a way that you can prevent this.

I assume that the web app is using clientside code to get your API, and so the IP address will always be the clients, and so you cannot limit your API to specific IPs.

Additionally, the calling domain is useless as you could fake this in postman or any other API sending tool.

This is a fight you won't easily win.

I'd ask the question of what ways can a user really abuse my API. If they want to use their token to perform actions on their account inside your application, then what does it matter if this happens within your application or outside of it?
How can they abuse your platform if they have the token? If there are ways to abuse it then you are better treating the root cause that **allows** the abuse to take place, rather than trying to limit how the token can be used.